# Is it possible to publish to NPM directly from a Github repository?

Tags: git, github, npm, package

Is it possible to publish to NPM directly from a GitHub repository?
basically just have npm inject all the structure from GitHub?

regards

Sean

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing - the documentation and various sites seem to 'hint' that it is able to do this - but there's no clean example that illustrates the process... my guess is that the repository property in a local package.json can specify the location in github --- but exactly how this might work is left unexplained... https://docs.npmjs.com/all#repository

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can, the answer is jspm... it's awesome